# Working out my code in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that allows the user to input his first name, middle name and family name but the catch is that he can choose not to input his middle name and the program will work out that it should display only the first and last name in that case.
The problem is I want to get the length of my "middle_name" Scanner and put that into a variable that would allow me to sort out two "if" statements

Here is the code in question:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Names {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.print("Enter your name : ");
            Scanner first_name = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter your middle name : ");
            Scanner middle_name = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter your last name : ");
            Scanner last_name = new Scanner(System.in);
            int x = Integer.parseInt(middle_name);
            if(x == 0) {
                System.out.println("First name : " + first_name);
                System.out.println("Last name : " + last_name);
            }
            if(x > 0) {
                System.out.println("First name : " + first_name);
                System.out.println("Middle name : " + middle_name);
                System.out.println("Last name : " + last_name);
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: Your name variables should be `String`s, not `Scanner`s. Use a single, separate variable for your `Scanner` and make use of that to get the names from the user.

Comment: You don't need three separate `Scanner` objects - just one will do.  Then call `nextLine` on your `Scanner` when you need input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is this:

1. have one Scanner that reads different lines
2. check middle_name for isEmpty() and only have three System.out statements

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Enter your name : ");
       String first_name = in.nextLine();
       System.out.print("Enter your middle name : ");
       String middle_name = in.nextLine();
       System.out.print("Enter your last name : ");
       String last_name = in.nextLine();

       System.out.println("First name : " + first_name);
       if(!middle_name.isEmpty()) {
           System.out.println("Middle name : " + middle_name);
       }
       System.out.println("Last name : " + last_name);

       in.close();
   }
   ```